# multi_json_1.3.6 error while using gem exception_notification", "~> 2.6.1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

```
Installing multi_json (1.3.6) /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/multi_json-1.3.6 (Errno::EACCES)
```

I even deleted Gemfile.lock but it is showing the error. I did use only

```
gem "exception_notification", "~> 2.6.1"
```

Please Help me.

Comment: please first format your post properly

Comment: now i don't know how to format this i am getting probleam installing multi_json 1.3.6

Comment: when i wright "sudo bundle install" it shows all the gem install but when i use rails s -p3004 then using error multi_json1.3.6 doesnot find

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the meaning of this error:

> Installing multi_json (1.3.6)
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:243:in
>   `mkdir': Permission denied -
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/multi_json-1.3.6
>   (Errno::EACCES)

you should go back and gain yourself some basic knowledge about unix and user-rights...

the problem is, that the user you are executing your bundle command with, is not allowed to execute `mkdir` in `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/` so this is basically a rights management problem.

Comment: you are right ,i did same thing in another system it is working.